# Python openpyxl add a new column

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have an .xlsx file like this:

```
item price
foo   5$
poo   3$
woo   7$
moo   2$
```

I want to use the openpyxl to open the file and add a new column to it like this:

```
item price  owner
foo   5$    Jim owns foo
poo   3$    Jack owns poo
woo   7$    John owns woo
moo   2$    Jay owns moo
```

Anyone can help me with how to do it?

My code:

```py
        file_location = 'excel_name.xlsx'
        df = pd.read_excel(file_errors_location, engine='openpyxl')
        for item in df['item']:
            df['sub'].append(f'bla bla owms {item}')
            df.to_excel('excel_me.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
```

Comment: To help; assuming that 'Jim', 'Jack', 'John', 'Jay' are not somewhere else in the sheet to be read, you can just make a list with the required names; iterate thru the used cells in the 'item' column and use a loop count to access the corresponding name from the names list; then as you loop through use these values to create your text and write into the third cell from the column you are looping thru.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need pandas for something this simple.
So working with 'item' column as column 'A'

```
import openpyxl as op


wb = op.load_workbook(r'foo.xlsx')
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
owner_list = ['owner', 'Jim', 'Jack', 'John', 'Jay']
for enum, cell in enumerate(ws['A']):
    row = enum+1
    if enum == 0:
        ws.cell(row=row, column=3).value = owner_list[enum]
    else:
        ws.cell(row=row, column=3).value = owner_list[enum] + " owns " + cell.value

wb.save('foo.xlsx')
```

Comment: The owner list is much bigger than this to be on a list and should be read from file

Comment: You should include all relevant information in the initial question to enable others to best help. That being said it is easy enough to create a list from a file. Search in Stackoverflow you'll find many answers covering this.